# Как открыть 3 вкладки в терминале Ubuntu 18.04 с помощью python3?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

Как с помощью python3 открыть 3 вкладки в терминале Ubuntu 18.04 и в каждой из них выполнить команду?

Comment: Открываешь терминал, в верхнем меню есть вкладка File(Файл), внутри будет кнопка New Tab (Новая вкладка), нажимаешь на него и открывается новая вкладка.. А выполнять файл также очень просто.. `python3 module_name.py arg1 arg2`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но немного не то; перефразировал вопрос для более точно

Comment: Хмм, понял вопрос, а не легче уж тогда использовать процессы?

Comment: нужно отслеживать работу скриптов, которые будут выполняться во вкладках и нужно чтобы были именно вкладки в одном окне, а как через процессы открыть 3 вкладки?